# how to read a specific line in .csv file in WPF (xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, csv

How can I code in  wpf -xaml (C#) to read a specific line in a .csv File.
Every button on the Periodic table I made goes to a new window which shows in a listview the specific things about it. But then my question how to do that?

```
public class Atomic
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
    public string Block { get; set; }
    public string Atomicnumber { get; set; }
    public string Stateat { get; set; }
    public string Electronconfiguration { get; set; }
    public string ChemspiderID { get; set; }

    public Atomic(string group, string period, string block, string atomicnumber, string stateat, string electronconfiguration, string chemspiderID)
    {
        Group = group;
        Period = period;
        Block= block;
        Atomicnumber = atomicnumber;
        Stateat = stateat;
        Electronconfiguration = electronconfiguration;
        ChemspiderID = chemspiderID;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Atomic> ReadCSV(string fileName)
{
    // We change file extension here to make sure it's a .csv file.
    // TODO: Error checking.
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".csv"));

    // lines.Select allows me to project each line as a Person. 
    // This will give me an IEnumerable<Person> back.
    return lines.Select(line =>
    {
        string[] data = line.Split(';');
        // We return a person with the data in order.
        return new Atomic(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a specific line you could do the following.

```
public Atomic ReadCSV(string fileName, int lineIndex)
{
    return File.ReadLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".csv"))
               .Skip(lineIndex)
               .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
               .Select(data => new Atomic(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6]))
               .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This will read the first `lineNumber` + 1 lines of the file take the last line read and create your `Atomic` object from that line.  If there are not enough lines it will return a `null` value.  If you prefer a one based index just change `.Skip(lineIndex)` to `.Skip(lineIndex - 1)`.

Comment: Thnx for the help. My problem is: When I click on the button btnHydrogen_MouseUp it has to read the first line in the .csv file. This also to do with the next button btnLithium_MouseUp to read the second line. Do I have to put a special code in every button event?